# How can I use percentages without randoms?

Tags: java

I want to run a code every 25% of the time:

Example:

```
public void run() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int num = rnd.nextInt(100);
    if(num < 25) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But the problem is that random classes aren't really accurate, and with some code performance issues it succeded 17/20 times with 5% chance and failed many more times with a 95% chance.
I have tried SecureRandom and Random classes.

Comment: you'll probably have greater success if you don't instantiate a new `Random()` for every single number you want.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean when you say the code "succeeded" or that it "failed".  You do understand, do you not, that even if you had a source of truly random numbers, you could not expect to use it to reliably choose one alternative in *exactly* a specified proportion of a finite number of trials?  There will be a spread around that target proportion.

Comment: @Alnitak you should make your comment an answer ;)

Comment: What @JohnBollinger said is exactly right.   20 runs is insufficient to eliminate the typical margin of error you'll.   You'd likely need to measure over several hundred or more runs to see a close approximation to 25%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches into running code 25% of the time. You can either run it every fourth time, or you can use a random generator to run it *on average* 25% of the time.

**Every 4th time**

```
class MyClass {
    private int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        if(this.i % 4 == 0) {
            // execute it
        }
        this.i++;
    }
}
```

**On average 25% of the time**

As mentioned in the comments it is important to not create a new Random generator every time you call the `run()` function, since this incurs a performance penalty and may also cause it to run not 25% of the time as required.

```
class MyClass {
    private Random rng = new Random();

    public void run() {
        int i = rng.nextInt(100);
        if(i < 25) {
            // execute it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP appears to be more interested in a stochastic process rather than something that executes every fourth time.

Comment: @bradimus not sure since the title contains "without randoms", I will update my answer to cover both cases.